# Remote PC running windows 11 turns off internet connection after a week online

Tags: windows, remote-access

I have this problem with a remote PC running a video surveillance application.

I am monitoring the PC with Cronitor so I know it has been online continuously for more than a week. Then, it turns off the internet connection, so I no longer can access with TeamViewer, but occasional web-requests goes through to Cronitor, so it still has internet connection available.

I have also installed a Raspberry Pi on the same LAN as the PC and I can see on the router that the PC has an assigned IP-address. I have tried several times going there or asked someone there to go a check on the PC and every time, they touch the PC it comes online almost instantly again, until a week later.

I have tried looking into the eventlog, can't find the root cause for this.

Comment: Which operating system on the PC? Are you sure it doesn't simply enter sleep?

Comment: Is this box unchecked in the device manager? "Allow the computer to turn off this device to save power"  There are additional registry keys if this doesn't work.

Comment: It is running windows 11. I am not sure if it enters sleep mode, would it wake up occasionally to send messages if it was in sleep mode?